# How to attach multiple files onto a page and show the progress on a progressbar. And upload the files to the server

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, tomahawk, mojarra

I know tamawhak provides a file upload component. But my requirement is to just display an 'Add file' button on the page(no input field is required). Upon clicking the button a choose file window should popup. Once the file to be attached is chosen, automatically the attachment should start with progress bar showing the progress of the attachment operation on  the same page. The user can do the same and attach multiple files. The user remains on the same page and upon attaching all  the files, they click on the submit button and upload the file.

I use JSF2.0 , I have no clue, how i do  this ?...Basically I need to implement a solution smillar to the attachment provided by gmail or simillar.

Thanks,
Aja

Answer (score 0):

I've done this exact thing a few times before, using [blueimp's jQuery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It takes a bit of tinkering to customize it to look and feel exactly like you want it, specifically hacking the file input to look like a button. The server side technology is not relevant as long as it can receive files.

Take a look at the demo and browse through the documentation. Don't expect this to be a simple solution though, it will take some work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more about how to use this plugin on a JSF application

Comment: @user1721801: No I can't, because I don't know anything about JSF. My answer is only in regard to the client side of the solution, but if you read the documentation it explains what the server side needs.